# how to get points mapping after opencv Stitching

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I use OpenCV Stitcher class to stitch multiple images together and I can get the final image. But I was wondering how can I get points mapping between original images and stitched image.

For example:

```
---------------------------
|                          |
|       ·(xa, ya)          |  (Image A)
|                          |
|                          |
|--------------------------
                  ---------------------------
                  |                          |
                  |                          |   (Image B)
                  |                          |
                  |                 ·(xb, yb)|
                  |--------------------------


                  ||
                  || after stitching
                  \/

 --------------------------------------------
|                                            |
|         ·(xc1, yc1)                        |  (Image C)
|                                            |
|                                 ·(xc2, yc2)|
|---------------------------------------------
```

How can I get the corresponding point of (xc1, yc1), which should be (xa, ya) in Image A, or (xc2, yc2), which should be (xb, yb) in Image B.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @ma3oun I have tried many OpenCV Stitcher examples written by Python, and read the OpenCV Docs, but got nothing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623700/opencv-how-to-map-between-corresponding-points-of-stitched-images  I found a similar question. Maybe I should read the OpenCV source code to learn how it is implemented?

Comment: It depends on the method you used for stitching. How did you stitched the images? or what command did you use?